# md5 hashed string to normal string

Tags: php, html

I've been inserting my password in my database with this POST

```
$txtPass = md5($_POST['txtPass']);
```

How could I then reverse this hash and turn the stored value in to a normal string?

Comment: I've done some slight rewording to your question. Feel free to revert it if its not quite what you meant to ask.

Comment: Sure, it's a hash, but don't look at it like it's hash when it's only encrypted. Encrypt it, add salt to it, iterate it numerous times and then we can talk. Now of course you can't "un-hash" a hash, what would be the point of the hash in the first place? You can only compare the results of hashed strings.

Comment: You are thinking the wrong way... We are encrypting passwords, not to decrypt them later but to protect them. If you need to compare later on if an input password matches with the encrypted value you have in your database, you will need to use the same hashing process and then compare the two hashed values. If they match you can assume   that the password entered is correct. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Hashing algorithms are *one way*. That means you cannot "undo" them. What you can do is compare a hashed value to them to see if they match.

```
if ($hashed_value === md5('some string')) {
    //they match
```

Comment: ok so maybe my solution to my problem is to leave my password blank in the update profile page of my project thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, a hash is (or should be) a one-way encryption method. However, with the evolution of [lookup tables](http://md5.gromweb.com/), storing hashes isn't as secure as it once was.

However, one way to make it a *little* better is to use a salt when you encrypt the password. For example:

```
$salt = "!@#$%^&";

// registration
$password = "letmein";
$dbPassword = md5($salt . $password); // f5eb04f754cff9cd2a4acae54f84dd90

// When they go to login:
$password = $_POST['password'];
$usrPassword = md5($salt . $password);
```

Then, even if they get the hash through a security hole it'll always have a salted prefix making it (almost never) match the actual hash in the database. So, using the example:

```
$password = $_POST['password']; // "!@#$%^&letmein"
$pwWithSalt = $salt . $password; // "!@#$%^&!@#$%^&letmein"
```

Granted, this is a simple example (and you wouldn't make the salt that obvious) however you can at least add another level of complexity which makes the look-up table a little less effective.

*I should also mention that [`crypt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) has this built-in and may be a better solution than md5*

Answer (score 0):

There is no PHP function to "decode" a MD5 hash. If you are really trying to find out the hash's original string then you could use [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

These enable you to lookup a known hash's original value. But there is no guarantee that you will be able to find the one you are looking for in any reasonable amount of time, or at all.